# Jquery date picker chage date format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am changing date picker date format but don't work the format of date does not change by deafault date format is like this **MM/DD/YYY**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#datetimepicker8").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
     icons: {
         time: "fa fa-clock-o",
         date: "fa fa-calendar",
         up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
       }
   });
  });
```

Bootstrap template:

```
     <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker8">
          <input type='text' class="form-control 
message"  id="datesfield"  name="dateSelect" required="true"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
     <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-
hidden="true"></i></span> </div>
                              </div>
```

Comment: Try date format with white spaces or dots instead of slashes, like this: `dateFormat : "dd mm yy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, replace code where applicable.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont just post the code try to explain it, so people seeing the answer can understand why it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not loading the right librairies (js, css) !

here is a working a example with the same code as yours:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#datetimepicker8").datepicker({
             dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
             icons: {
                 time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                 date: "fa fa-calendar",
                 up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
               }
           });
          });
```

https://jsbin.com/korunucilo/1/edit?html,js,output